# Работа с векторами Java

Tags: java, структуры-данных

Задание таково: создать класс `ArrayVector`, реализующий работу с векторами (набор вещественных чисел, координат) и базовые операции векторной арифметики. Класс должен удовлетворять следующим требованиям.

Экземпляр должен соответствовать вектору фиксированной длины (она задается как параметр конструктора).
Должны быть реализованы следующие методы:

- доступа к элементам вектора (получения значения и изменения значения), (`getElement(), setElement()`);
- получения «длины» вектора (количества его элементов),  (`getSize()`);
- поиска минимального и максимального значений из элементов вектора, (`min(), max()`);
- сортировки вектора (по возрастанию или убыванию – на ваш выбор), (`sort()`);
- нахождения евклидовой нормы, (`getNorm()`);
- умножения вектора на число, (`mult()`);
- сложения двух векторов, (`sum()`);
- нахождения скалярного произведения двух векторов (`scalarMult()`).

В процессе выполнения задания НЕЛЬЗЯ пользоваться утилитными классами Java (кроме метода `Math.sqrt()`).
Точка входа программы может быть реализована в классе, в отладочных целях, но не обязательна к написанию.

Я совсем начинающий, так что просьба громко не смеяться:) Я так понимаю необходимо написание класса, инкапсулирующего вектор (на основе массива) и поддерживающего ряд операций с вектором и над векторами. Вопрос: правильно ли я представил себе задачу и как наиболее логично её реализовать? Код:

```
public class ArrayVector {

    double [] a={2,23,32};
    public double[] getA() {
        return a;
    }
    public void setA(double[] a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    public void dlina(double a){
        double dlina;

    //как обратиться к массиву и выполнять векторные операции?

    }
}
```

Comment: setA() и getA() в ТЗ я не увидел, а вот конструктор-то сразу напишите. 

В нем инициализируйте вектор нулями и запомните длину (это аргумент конструктора), который Вы будете возвращать методом "dlina" (*ну и названьеце*)

Comment: avp, а можете, если, конечно, не трудно, примерно описать в коде свой ответ?)

Comment: а что если я натворю подобное: 
public class ArrayVector {
 double [] a={2,23,32};
 public double[] getA() {
  return a;
 }
 public void setA(double[] a) {
  this.a = a;
 }
 double dlina;
 public double getDlina() {
  return dlina;
 }
 public void setDlina(double dlina) {
  this.dlina = dlina;
 }
 ArrayVector vector = new ArrayVector();
 public void getSize(){
  dlina=Math.sqrt(vector.a[0]+vector.a[1]+vector.a[2]);
 }
 public static void main(String[] args){
 
vector.getSize();
System.out.println(dlina);
 }
}
ругается мол не статичный vector и dlina

Comment: И правильно делает, а если так ? :) Почитайте внимательнее о статических методах и полях.

    public class ArrayVector {
        double[] a = {2, 23, 32};
        double dlina;


        public void getSize() {
            for (double value : a) {
                dlina += value;
            }
        }

        // ... остальные методы

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ArrayVector vector = new ArrayVector();
            vector.getSize();
            System.out.println(vector.getDlina());
        }
    }

Comment: @FusionF Вынесите ваш класс в отдельный файл, см. http://hashcode.ru/questions/154106/java-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-static-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5

Comment: masterMind, Вы проверяли этот код? Ругается на vector.getDlina() The method getDlina() is undefined for the type ArrayVector :(

Answer (score 6):

накидал код, который будем надеятся поможет вам, в изучении языка. пример состоит из 3х классов:

1) **IArrayVector** - задает базовые методы для вашего 'ArrayVector' (он гарантирует что все реализации этого интерфейса будут иметь необходимые для вас методы)
2) **AArrayVector** - реализует некоторый общий функционал для всех допустимых реализаций ArrayVector (этот функционал общий, и врядли будет менятся для отдельных реализаций)
3) **IntegerArrayVector** - пример простой реализации (конечно же там еще много чего не работает)

1)

```
public interface IArrayVector<E extends Comparable<E>> {
    int getSize();
    E getElement(int index);
    void setElement(int index, E element);

    E min();
    E max();
    E getNorm();

    IArrayVector<E> sort();
    IArrayVector<E> mult(E number);
    IArrayVector<E> sum(IArrayVector<E> vector);
    IArrayVector<E> scalarMult(IArrayVector<E> vector);
}
```

2)

```
public abstract class AArrayVector<E extends Comparable<E>> implements
        IArrayVector<E>, Cloneable {
    private E[] elements = null;

    public AArrayVector(int size) {
        elements = createArray(size);
    }

    @Override
    public final E getElement(int index) {
        if (null == elements || index > getSize()) {
            return null;
        }

        return (E) elements[index];
    }

    @Override
    public final void setElement(int index, E element) {
        if (0 <= index && index <= getSize()) {
            elements[index] = element;
        }
    }

    protected abstract E[] createArray(int size);

    @Override
    public int getSize() {
        if (null == elements) {
            return 0;
        }
        return elements.length;
    }

    @Override
    public final E max() {
        E max = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < getSize(); i++) {
            // if max element is not found use the first one
            // else use greater one
            if (null == max || (1 > max.compareTo(elements[i]))) {
                max = elements[i];
            }
        }
        return max;
    }

    @Override
    public final E min() {
        E min = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            // if max element is not found use the first one
            // else use greater one
            if (null == min || (-1 < min.compareTo(elements[i]))) {
                min = elements[i];
            }
        }
        return min;
    }

    @Override
    public AArrayVector<E> sort() {
        AArrayVector<E> cloned = (AArrayVector<E>) clone();
        if (2 > getSize()) {
            return cloned;
        }
        return cloned;
    }

    @Override
    protected AArrayVector<E> clone() {
        AArrayVector<E> instance = createInstance();
        for (int i = 0; i < getSize(); i++) {
            instance.setElement(i, getElement(i));
        }

        return instance;
    }

    protected abstract AArrayVector<E> createInstance();
}
```

3)

```
public class IntegerArrayVector extends AArrayVector<Integer> {

    public IntegerArrayVector(int size) {
        super(size);
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer[] createArray(int size) {
        return new Integer[size];
    }

    @Override
    protected AArrayVector<Integer> createInstance() {
        return new IntegerArrayVector(getSize());
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getNorm() {
        // TODO - implement
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public IArrayVector<Integer> mult(Integer number) {
        // create clone of this object
        AArrayVector<Integer> copy = createInstance();

        // TODO: multiply each element by number value

        // return result
        return copy;
    }

    @Override
    public IArrayVector<Integer> scalarMult(IArrayVector<Integer> vector) {
        // TODO implement
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public IArrayVector<Integer> sum(IArrayVector<Integer> vector) {
        // TODO implement
        return null;
    }

    // usage
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IArrayVector<Integer> vector = new IntegerArrayVector(3);
        vector.setElement(0, 7);
        vector.setElement(0, 3);
        vector.setElement(0, 5);

        vector.sort();
    }

}
```

p.s. курс математики я уже забыл, поэтому заранее прошу прощения за допущеные ошибки

Comment: jmu, Вы, сударь, конечно, жжёте)) Это действительно такую махину нужно для реализации этой шушары? И public static void main(String[] args) ругается мол "The method main cannot be declared static; static methods can only be declared in a static or top level type" (Я в Eclipse ваяю:) )

Comment: @jmu, пока это творение может только запутать, напугать и отвратить TC от Java.

Comment: @avp, подскажите тогда что-нибудь более лаконичное..

Comment: 2 @FusionF: мне не лень, кроме того, я люблю java именно за ее про-ООП подход к решению задач. На счет eclipse, я не в блокноте писал, вы точно раскидали класы по отдельным файлам или просто убрали у 2х паблик модификатор ?

2 @avp: вполне вероятно, думаете стоило не добавлять generics ?

Comment: @jmu, сами подумайте. Видимо одно из первых заданий. В тексте задания требуется работа с массивом  double. 

Зачем сейчас ему generics, интерфейс и т.п.?

--

Думаю один класс с одним конструктором и массивом инициализируемым (по умолчанию) нулями будет в самый раз. Тогда никакие проверки на null внутри методов не нужны. Можно оставить стандартное для массивов поведение ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException и не проверять индексы и т.п.

--

Но, думаю для TC будет полезней самому это написать. Пусть пишет варианты, советуется и если не получается задает **конкретные** вопросы.

Answer (score 1):

Неплохое начало..

```
//как обратиться к массиву и выполнять векторные операции?
ArrayVector vector = new ArrayVector();
vector.sort();
```

Comment: Gorets, а что делает vector.sort() ? В задании Нельзя ж подгружать ничего?)

Comment: сортировки вектора (по возрастанию или убыванию – на ваш выбор), (sort()); - реализуешь - будет работать ))