# Реализация метода сложения векторов

Tags: java

Пишу задачу на java. Суть -- реализация класса `ArrayVector`. В принципе все понятно, возникли сомнения с одним методом. Все ли правильно я делаю?

```
public ArrayVector sum(ArrayVector anotherVector) {

    int leng=anotherVector.getSize()<arrayelements.length?anotherVector.getSize():arrayelements.length;
    for(int i=0;i<leng;i++)
    {
        arrayelements[i]+=anotherVector.get(i);
    }
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Это тернарный оператор такой `arrayelements.length?anotherVector.getSize():arrayelements.length`? `arrayelements.length` boolean возвращает?

Comment: Метод как метод. Можно только сделать поаккуратнее и покрасивше. Хотя, судя примеру, Вас это не шибко-то и ... заботит.

Comment: `leng` это `leg` в котором лишняя буква `n`?

Answer (score 2):

Алгебра(векторная) нам говорит - Любые два вектора одной размерности можно сложить. Векторы разной размерности складывать нельзя.

ArrayVector должен иметь определенную размерность. Если это нечто универсальное, то тогда надо проверять размерность складываемых векторов и при несовпадении выдавать исключение.

Comment: Может у него не алгебраические вектора? Ведь ни алгебра, ни прочая математика в вопросе не упоминается.

Comment: To @banme А какой еще? Ветор как динамический массив (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) в данном случае не подходит, Еак как там заложена другая логика. Метод `sum` явно указывает на алгебраическую сущность объекта. И да! http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/154777/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-java

Comment: Да фиг его знает

Comment: В задании указано следующее: Реализовать класс для работы с вектором (набор вещественных чисел, координат) и базовые операции векторной арифметики. Насколько я понял, речь идет о векторе, который одномерный массив. По поводу сложения векторов разной длины указано следующее: Складывает вектор с другим вектором, результат запоминает в элементах данного вектора. Если векторы имеют разный размер, последние элементы большего вектора не учитываются.